# CCLabelTTF set automatically the font size

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cclabelttf

Is there a way to set automatically the font size of a CCLabelTTF text in base of the length of the string? 
because I have a number that increment and if it gets too big collides with a close image...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in cocos2d version 3.x, you can

```
CCLabelTTF *label = [CCLabelTTF whatever ....];
label.dimensions = CGSizeMake(widthYouWant,heightYouWant);
label.adjustFontSizeToFit = YES;
label.minimumFontSize = 8;
```

... not tested, just from memory.